# Load Testing RTMP connections

Tags: flash, webcam, load-testing, rtmp, wowza

I am using [Wowza Media Server](http://www.wowza.com/)'s webcam record capability in a project. It records the webcam feed over [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) which is connected to via a flash file. It's all working fine, but I need to stress/load test the functionality to check how it'll scale up.

I've done http load testing several times which is fine but I'm not sure how best to simulate RTMP connections. Obviously by the nature of webcam recordings it's probably quite a hard thing to simulate, but any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm working on the same kind of project but with Red5 and honnestly we never have done any RTMP stress test. First we have been relying on Red5's specs and then, luckily, our projects were of growing sizes. What about opening a beta version to a limited set of users?

Comment: The nature of the project has no beta. It's going to be going from 0 to several hundred thousand concurrent users very quickly. Luckily the webcam usage rate won't be as high as that. We have used wowza before up to around 1 thousand concurrents, but no idea if we had way too much power behind it. Thanks for the suggestion though, will let you know if I find a good tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wowza has a load testing tool.  [Flash RTMP Load Test Tool](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?122)

*Wowza Media Server provides a Flash RTMP load testing tool. This tool can be used to generate RTMP load on a single Wowza server to test configuration and performance.
The Load Test Tool requires a subscription or perpetual license. To request the Load Test Tool, send an email request with the following information to test@wowzamedia.com:*

- *Name*
- *Company name*
- *Last 4-digits of subscription or perpetual license*
- *Reason for use*

I've used it a couple times myself and can attest to its usefulness.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Flazr](http://flazr.com/): http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/flazr/index.php?title=Load_Testing.

There's a video demonstration on [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wa2bDQLKf8s).